# How do I test replace method in mocha?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, chai

I am very new to mocha and got stuck with testing below functionality. I have following string `replace_underscore_with_hyphen`. I am replacing this with `replace-underscore-with-hyphen` using below functionality.

```
const type = "replace_underscore_with_hyphen";
     type = type.replace(/_/ig, '-');
```

But please may I know how do I test this functionality in mocha.

Comment: This depends on where this piece of code occurs. The question doesn't contain the context for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can test that final string contains hyphen, and doesn't underscores:

```
const replaceUnderscores = () => {
  const type = "replace_underscore_with_hyphen";
  return type.replace(/_/ig, '-');
}

it('should replace underscores with hyphen', () => {
  const replaced = replaceUnderscores();
  expect(replaced).not.toContain('_');
  expect(replaced).toContain('-');
});
```